# How would I use Orb detector with image homography?

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, homography, orb

I'm wanting to use orb detectors to draw a bounding box around a found image, similarly to the example here, which is using sift detectors: [SIFT Refrence](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html)

The Linked example uses a FlannBasedMatcher. My Code uses a BFMatcher. I have no preference in the Matcher used.

```
        MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10

        img1 = cv2.imread('box.png',0)
        img2 = cv2.imread('box_in_scene.png',0)

        orb = cv2.ORB_create()

        kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
        kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

        bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
        matches = bf.match(des1,des2)
```

How would I continue this code to use homography to draw around the box_in_scene image?

**EDIT:** I tried the following, but the output wasn't as expected.

```
src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in matches[:50] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in matches[:50] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()
h,w = img1.shape
pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)
```

Comment: if the matching is good, transform the points (0,0);(img1.cols,0);(0,img1.rows) and (img1.cols,img1.rows) with the homography and draw lines between them.

Comment: @Micka `matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in matches[:50] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)

dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in matches[:50] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)

M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)

matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

h,w = img1.shape

pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)

dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)`

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work accurately.

Comment: This is my result. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IS3w.png The `red` box is by `flann`, the `green` box is by `match`. They are nearly the same.

Comment: @Silencer Did you use Orb or SIFT?

Comment: All are orb, but the matching method are different.

Comment: @Silencer Could you guide me on how to progress after the first section of code i posted? I'm basically looking for your output but that it only shows the right image with the box around? (no blue lines)

Comment: Given your code before, then you can do this: `cv2.polylines(img2, [np.int32(dst)], True, (0,0,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA);cv2.imshow("res", img2);cv2.waitKey()`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This my result.

[image]

---

The code (the description was wrote as the comment):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2017.11.26 23:27:12 CST

## Find object by orb features matching

import numpy as np
import cv2
imgname = "box.png"          # query image (small object)
imgname2 = "box_in_scene.png" # train image (large scene)

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 4

## Create ORB object and BF object(using HAMMING)
orb = cv2.ORB_create()
img1 = cv2.imread(imgname)
img2 = cv2.imread(imgname2)

gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

## Find the keypoints and descriptors with ORB
kpts1, descs1 = orb.detectAndCompute(gray1,None)
kpts2, descs2 = orb.detectAndCompute(gray2,None)

## match descriptors and sort them in the order of their distance
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
matches = bf.match(descs1, descs2)
dmatches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

## extract the matched keypoints
src_pts  = np.float32([kpts1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in dmatches]).reshape(-1,1,2)
dst_pts  = np.float32([kpts2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in dmatches]).reshape(-1,1,2)

## find homography matrix and do perspective transform
M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
h,w = img1.shape[:2]
pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)

## draw found regions
img2 = cv2.polylines(img2, [np.int32(dst)], True, (0,0,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imshow("found", img2)

## draw match lines
res = cv2.drawMatches(img1, kpts1, img2, kpts2, dmatches[:20],None,flags=2)

cv2.imshow("orb_match", res);

cv2.waitKey();cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```