# Matching ORB Features and Using Them to Find Homography

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, orb, corner-detection

I have a video and a template image and I want to extract an image that represents the template image.
In my method, the results are not satisfying(the extracted image is juddering) and I could not be able to solve the problem. I am asking if there is any possible way to avoid paddling or another method to solve this problem.

1. I found the features with the ORB and matched them.
2. Used cv2.findHomography() function to get homography.
3. Finally, used cv2.warpPerspective() function.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videos/gunduz/part1.mp4')
orb = cv2.ORB_create()  # Registration works with at least 50 points
im2 = cv2.imread('videos/gunduz/tmp1.jpg')
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

while True:
    success, im1 = cap.read()

    img1 = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # find the keypoints and descriptors with orb
    kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1, None)  # kp1 --> list of keypoints

    matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv2.DESCRIPTOR_MATCHER_BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING)

    # Match descriptors.
    matches = matcher.match(des1, des2, None)  # Creates a list of all matches, just like keypoints

    # Sort them in the order of their distance.
    matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)

    img3 = cv2.drawMatches(im1, kp1, im2, kp2, matches[:], None)

    cv2.imshow("Matches image", img3)

    points1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)  # Prints empty array of size equal to (matches, 2)
    points2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)

    for i, match in enumerate(matches[:]):
        points1[i, :] = kp1[match.queryIdx].pt  # gives index of the descriptor in the list of query descriptors
        points2[i, :] = kp2[match.trainIdx].pt  # gives index of the descriptor in the list of train descriptors

    h, mask = cv2.findHomography(points1, points2, cv2.RANSAC)  # You can also use 8 point.

    # Use homography
    height, width, channels = im2.shape
    im1Reg = cv2.warpPerspective(im1, h, (width, height))  # Applies a perspective transformation to an image.

    cv2.imshow("Registered image", im1Reg)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: First off: thank you for commenting your code. Second, can you post the image and the video so that we can see what you're working with and check our solutions against it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I use Orb detector with image homography?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496287/how-would-i-use-orb-detector-with-image-homography)