# TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'DescriptorMatcher' or its derivative) with ORB_create()

Tags: python, opencv, homography, orb, overlapping-matches

I would like to compute the homography matrix using cv2. For that, I was using `ORB_create()` first and followed the discussion in [How would I use Orb detector with image homography?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496287/how-would-i-use-orb-detector-with-image-homography).

However, while doing  `matches = bf.match(descs1, descs2)`, I am getting an error

```
File "/var/folders/_s/sk0g6rrx3_v_fl0y8zybdb8c0000gn/T/ipykernel_32180/2073887229.py", line 2, in <module>
    matches = bf.match(descs1, descs2)

TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'DescriptorMatcher' or its derivative)
```

What causes this issue and how can I resolve it?

**EDIT**

Here is the part that worked for me:

```
MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 20
kpts1, descs1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kpts2, descs2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

## match descriptors and sort them in the order of their distance
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
matches = bf.match(descs1, descs2)
```

**img1** and **img2** are grayscale images and type of numpy array of shape 128x128. After `bf.match` I am getting the error above.

Comment: Show us a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: Can you please print the type of the input variables?

Comment: Could you try `bf = cv2.BFMatcher_create(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)` instead?